# Linux - How to bind a network connection to only use specific port

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, port

I have 2 network connections, one of them (Wired) needs to be used exclusively for port 22 on this machine.

Is it possible to only use the wired device for a given port?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have a static IP on wired interface or you have reservation on DHCP server you can do that in this way:
Edit sshd config file

```
#vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Go to specific lines that shows

```
ListenAddress *
```

If you wish to bind ssh to existing 1 or 2 IP address, let's say 192.168.1.5 and 192.168.1.7, this could be done by changing the above sshd_config line(s) to

```
ListenAddress 192.168.1.5
ListenAddress 192.168.1.7
```

and Restart sshd daemon.
The other way is to setup your firewall to allow incoming traffic on port 22 only from wired interface, for example: eth0 and disallow from other. The order of commands is important.

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT ! -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

Comment: Thanks Mariaczi, if I use ListenAddress on say: 192.168.1.5 that `192.168.1.5` would still be used for other ports as well? Ah yes, I see. Then I believe I would need to use the firewasll.

Comment: Yes, sure. `ssh service` use only this port(s) you have in your configuration.

Comment: Ye, but I'd like it so that the rest of the machine *does not* use this network. Basically i'd like the network card to be only used for port 22

Comment: Also what does the ! mean in the rules then? :)

Comment: If you want to use this network interface for ssh service only - firewall is your friend and the solution :)